# Firefox in Xubuntu is playing mp2t / .ts / webm video files with a deep / slow / distorted / off audio sound

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, audio, video

> Firefox latest, v70, Ubuntu 18.04

`mp2t` / `.ts` video plays fine, but audio plays really distorted, very deep like the audio has been slowed down incredibly (even though it plays at same speed).

I've tried restarted with no addons to no avail.

Any idea why this file format plays incredibly deep sounding from Firefox? It plays perfectly fine when downloaded through mplayer or VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT: Root issue and solution

It seems that custom user agent strings via about:config value and an extension were directing websites to return an invalid HLS stream for Firefox to read. Disabling these user agent changes has led to the issue resolving itself.

---

Go to `about:config` > `media.mediasource.mp4.enabled` set to **false**

The full answer with steps can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200048/firefox-in-xubuntu-is-playing-mp2t-ts-awebm-video-files-with-a-deep-slow